# Determine how a linear mapping acts on a vector in general, by looking at how it acts on the basis.

Tags: linear-algebra

My doubt is can this be done if the two vector spaces involved in the case are not isomorphic.
We have the linear mapping $A: R^2 \to R^3$ and we know that $A(1,0) = (1,1,1)$ and $A(1,1) = (0,-1,1)$. Because the vectors $(0,1)$ and $(1,1)$ are a basis for $R^2$, can we express the general vector $\vec {x} = (a,b)$ as a linear combination of the two vectors of the basis and see how $A$ acts on this linear combination, in order to see how $A$ acts on the general vector $\vec {x} = (a,b)$.
Am I right or this can be also done if the basis is a standard basis, or maybe if only the two vector spaces are isomorphic?

If this is not the case, how can we explicitly determine how $A$ acts on every vector given only the images of the vectors $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done and has nothing to do with surjectivity or injectivity of the linear map $A: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^3$, only with the linearity. Let $(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2$. Then you can write 
$$ (x,y) = \alpha (1,0) + \beta(1,1) \; ,$$
since $\{ (1,0), (1,1) \}$ is a basis of $\Bbb R^2$. Applying the linear map $A$ on this equation gives you 
$$ A(x,y) = \alpha A(1,0) + \beta A(1,1) = \alpha(1,1,1) + \beta (0,-1,1) \; . $$

Comment: So we can only see this if we have a given basis? If we have a set that is not a basis and we only know how the mapping $A$ acts on this set, knowing that, can we also see how the mapping acts on a general vector from the vector space?

Comment: @user92 Yes, if you only know how the linear map $A: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^3$ acts on two linearly dependant vectors, say $\{ (1,0), (2,0) \}$, you cannot deduce from from that, how $A$ acts on a arbitrary vector $(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Every vector $\pmatrix{a\\b}\in\mathbb R^2$ is uniquely expressed as
$$
\pmatrix{a\\b} = (a-b) \pmatrix{1\\0} + b \pmatrix{1\\1}
$$
in terms of your basis. Hence
$$
f\pmatrix{a\\b} = (a-b)\, f\pmatrix{1\\0} + b \, f\pmatrix{1\\1}
$$
for any linear map $f\colon \mathbb R^2 \to V$, where $V$ is any real vector space.

Comment: why not to assume that $(a,b)$ are the components in the basis $(1,0), (1,1)$?

Comment: @janmarqz The components of $\pmatrix{a\\b}$ in the basis $\pmatrix{1\\0},\pmatrix{1\\1}$ are $(a-b)$ and $b$. I'm not sure what you're asking.